# Why do I need to remove `inner sep` from text width in node to have correct width?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I am trying to create an official (looking) form. When using tikz to draw the fields I need to subtract `inner sep` from the intended width of the field to get the correct width.

```
\documentclass[DIN, a4, 11pt]{scrartcl}

% encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

% font
\usepackage{tgheros} 
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}

% dimensions
\newlength\margin
\setlength\margin{2cm}
\newlength\innersep
\setlength\innersep{\dimexpr3pt\relax}

\newcommand{\numberunits}{8}

% basic length unit (blu)
\newlength\blu
\setlength\blu{\dimexpr(\paperwidth-2\margin)/\numberunits\relax}

% basic height unit (bhu)
\newlength\bhu
\setlength\bhu{\dimexpr1.5em\relax}

% tikz styles
\tikzstyle{textfield} = [text depth = \bhu, draw, anchor=north west, outer sep=0, inner sep=\innersep, font = {\tiny\sffamily}]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture} [overlay, remember picture,shift={(current page.north west)}]
        \coordinate (outer_border_north_west) at (\margin, -\margin);
        \coordinate (outer_border_south_east) at (\dimexpr\paperwidth-\margin\relax,-\dimexpr\paperheight-\margin\relax);
        \draw (outer_border_north_west) rectangle (outer_border_south_east);
        
        \node[textfield, text width = 3\blu-2\innersep] (Name) at (outer_border_north_west) {Name};
        \node[textfield, text width = 3\blu-2\innersep, right = 0cm of Name.east] (First Name) {First Name};
        \node[textfield, text width = 2\blu-2\innersep, right = 0cm of First Name.east] (Birth Date) {Birth Date};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Why is that? It is the INNER separation and not the outer... right?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Have a look at `\tikzset` instead

Comment: The inner seps will get added to the dimension of the node's textbox, it is padding around the text for the actual path of the node. The outer sep is another padding around the path. This is where the anchors lie. Inner + outer sep around the text.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: Thanks for the explanation. Is there another way to set the width of the border of a node that does not require to add the `inner sep`?

Comment: @mrCarnivore You can use `minimum width` which is used if text width and 2× inner sep is smaller than that. That will still add the outer seps for the anchor position but since you set that to `0` it wouldn't matter. Maybe it would be better to draw the fields with a rectangle path (or another node) and add the actual text as separate node in the top left corner of that rectangle.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: That works, however then the text is no longer in the top left corner but is centered... adding another node for the border is, of course, possible but I think more complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd draw the rectangles as rectangles and the small text labels as nodes that are in the top-left corner of those rectangles and have `anchor = north west` set. I'm sure they wouldn't be longer than the actual rectangle (otherwise we'd need to make sure they have a max text width but then rectangle and the whole row wouldn't grow downwards anyway).

I've also just set up the appropriate page settings via `geometry`, i.e. a `margin` of 2cm on all sides.

Instead of `\numberunits` I'm using a value-key (as well as for the individual columns) and am setting the *x* vector to be the length of one such unit.

`trim left` and `trim right` are used so that the linewidths of the rectangles doesn't contribute to the bounding box and raises an overfull hbox error. Similarly, `baseline` is used so that the picture also has some depth (and doesn't jump to the next page).

Inside the `form` environment the `\row` macro takes one optional argment that sets keys in the `/tikz/form` namespace and one mandatory argument that is a list of the elements in that row.

You can always set `columns` or `height` to a common default on the outer scope and only specify variations of that default in the optional argument of `\row`.

---

I could also imagine a `&` and `\\` powered input (with some additiona pre-processing) so that it almost looks like a normal matrix/tabular you're inputting (but in actuality the same or a similar `\path` with the `foreach` loop will be executed).

The input syntax could almost anything. The most straight-forward one to implement is this, I think.

### Code

```
\documentclass[paper=A4, 11pt]{scrartcl}
% encoding
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% packages
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,footskip=1cm]{geometry}
% font
\usepackage{tgheros}
%\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\tikzset{
  form/.cd,
  .code=\pgfqkeys{/tikz/form}{#1},
    textfield/.style={anchor=north west, font=\tiny\sffamily},
    @columns/.code=%
      \pgfmathparse{#1}\edef\pgfmathcounter{\pgfinteval{\pgfmathcounter+1}}%
      \pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/form/col \pgfmathcounter\space width}{\pgfmathresult}%
      \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathresult+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/form/units}}%
      \pgfkeyssetevalue{/tikz/form/units}{\pgfmathresult},
    columns/.style={
      /tikz/form/units/.initial=0,
      /utils/exec=\def\pgfmathcounter{0},
      /tikz/form/@columns/.list={#1}},
    columns={3,3,2},       % initialize 3/3/2 column grid
    height/.initial=2.5em, % initialize row height
    row/.style=draw}       % initialize row style
\makeatletter % let us setup the \row command here without having to globally def it
\newcommand*\tikzform@row[2][]{%
  \path[form={#1},form/row,x=\linewidth/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/form/units})]
    (@top left) foreach[count=\colCnt] \col in {#2}{
      node[form/textfield]{\col}
      rectangle ++(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/form/col \colCnt\space width},
                  -\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/form/height})
      ++ (up:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/form/height})
    }
    coordinate (@top left)
      at ([shift=(down:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/form/height})]@top left);}
\newenvironment*{form}[1][]{%
  \par\noindent
  \tikzpicture[trim left=+0pt, trim right=+\linewidth,baseline=1em,form={#1}]
  \draw (0pt,0pt) rectangle (\linewidth,\textheight);
  \coordinate (@top left) at (0pt,\textheight);
  \let\row\tikzform@row
}{\endtikzpicture\par}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{form}
\row{Name, First Name, Birth Date}
\row[columns={8, 2}, height=4em]{Street, No.}
\row[columns={3,2,9}, height=1.5em]{Country, ZIP, City}
\end{form}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That is an interesting solution. And does enable me to use some things flexible. However, it does not easily enable multiple lines of the form with different numbers of boxes. (I do have to admit that that was not part of my question since it got lost while creating a minimal example...) I just realized that you `tikzset` enables parameters. I was not aware of that. Just taking over the `trim right`and `trim left` did not work to solve my issue. I will continue analyzing your answer.

Comment: I saw I can extend the numbers of cols and give every col a initial width of 0. So only the ones I use and give widths for will be drawn. If I could also add the text for the fields as a parameter it would work. Is that possible?

Comment: @mrCarnivore I've updated my answer with a more natural input syntax, I believe.

Comment: That seems to be quite elegant and powerful. I will try to understand your solution and learn from it. Thank you very much.